# How do i add a Custom View inside one of the row in a List View in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my MainActivity. I use custom adapter to inflate different layout for different rows in my ListView, by checking if the String object provided as argument to the custom adapter equals a certain value say "A" , But when i do that i get the below inflation error from my custom view

```
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): Process: co.example.customviewtest, PID: 14455
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class co.example.customviewtest.MyCustomView
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
10-31 19:28:34.915: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tell the listview that your adapter works with multiple types of views. In order to do that you'll have to override these 2 methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

That will tell the system how to recycle your views.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @azertiti , but i have already done that. Everything works fine if i dont include my custom view , if i have a basic simple another layout in place of the custom view , it works fine, the issue is when using the custom view .

Answer (score 0):

Is 'co.example.customviewtest.MyCustomView' a proper full name of your custom view? Is package name really starts with 'co' not 'com'?  Did you provide a two parameters constructor in your 'MyCustomView' class?

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: i thing i can name my package as and how i want it.. basically its supposed to be a reverse domain name , correct me if i am wrong
i.e : if my domain name is say example.com , its reverse domain will be com.example
likewise example.co => co.example 
the rest of the part is just my name of the project
co.example.<MY_PROJECT_NAME>.<CLASS_NAME>

Comment: And yes i did provide the two parameter constructor, i would like to mention my custom view contains just a webview , if that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Simply, I would like to ensure, that 'co' is not a typo (in your xml), that raise InflateException.

Comment: no , its not a typo , i simple named my package in that way.